# Bind a block to cells in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

when scrolling a table, the blue block in it does not move along with the cells, can this be somehow fixed?

**ignore this text, I just don’t know what else to write ->** It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      overflow: auto;
      width: 75%;
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 40px;
      height: 20px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .cell {
      background-color: blue;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>

  <script>
    function getPosition(el) {
      let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        scrollLeft = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
        scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop

      return {
        top: rect.top + scrollTop,
        left: rect.left + scrollLeft
      }
    }

    function tableInit(parent, row, cols) {
      const table = document.createElement('table')
      let counter = 0

      for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr')
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++, counter++) {
          let td = document.createElement('td')
          td.textContent = counter
          td.classList.add(counter)
          tr.appendChild(td)
        }
        table.appendChild(tr)
      }
      parent.appendChild(table)
    }

    let container = document.querySelector('.container')
    tableInit(container, 7, 100)

    let table = document.querySelector('table')
    let td = document.getElementsByClassName('104')[0]

    let cell = document.createElement('div')
    cell.classList.add('cell')
    cell.setAttribute('style',
      `top: ${getPosition(td).top}px;
        left: ${getPosition(td).left}px;
        height: ${td.clientHeight + 2}px;
        width: ${td.clientWidth * 2}px;`)
    table.appendChild(cell)

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The blue block moves up the cells! How do you need the blue block to move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your table or your container a position, so that your browser knows how it flows in the DOM. Without this, your `.cell` is absolute to the container not the scrolling children.

Watch out for the second line in `tableInit()`. That's one possible solution.

```js
function getPosition(el) {
  let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop

  return {
    top: rect.top + scrollTop,
    left: rect.left + scrollLeft
  }
}

function tableInit(parent, row, cols) {
  const table = document.createElement('table')
  table.setAttribute('style', `position: relative`) // Give the table a position
  let counter = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr')
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++, counter++) {
      let td = document.createElement('td')
      td.textContent = counter
      td.classList.add(counter)
      tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    table.appendChild(tr)
  }
  parent.appendChild(table)
}

let container = document.querySelector('.container')
tableInit(container, 7, 100)

let table = document.querySelector('table')
let td = document.getElementsByClassName('104')[0]

let cell = document.createElement('div')
cell.classList.add('cell')
cell.setAttribute('style',
  `top: ${getPosition(td).top}px;
    left: ${getPosition(td).left}px;
    height: ${td.clientHeight + 2}px;
    width: ${td.clientWidth * 2}px;`)
table.appendChild(cell)
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 75%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.cell {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the blue block to stay put in its position alongside the empty blocks, you need to make the container relative.

```
.container {
      position: relative;
   }
```